# Determine available space before creating FileOutputStream from ParcelFileDescriptor from Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT

Tags: android, android-intent, storage, filesize, intentservice

I have an Android app that I am creating which has a function to allow the user to export their created data to a zip file. I ask them to select a folder on their Android device to hold the zip file - it will most likely be an external SD card. I use Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT in order to create a new file, but I am unable to capture the device path so that I can check to make sure that there is enough storage space to hold the zip file.
I am aware that the Uri returned from ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT does not contain directory information as a way to provide for greater security.
Does anyone know of a means to determine available storage without assuming that the user has selected the SDCard storage?

Here is my code, abbreviated:

```
public void Export_Operation_Init() {

        //https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#create-file
        // Allow the user to choose a location to save the export using the system's file picker.
        Intent intent_GetExportSaveAsFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);

        intent_GetExportSaveAsFile.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent_GetExportSaveAsFile.setType("application/zip");

        //Generate the name of the zip file:
        Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
        final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
        String sTemp = sdf.format(timestamp);
        String sZipFileName = "NHComicManager_Backup_" + sTemp + ".zip";

        intent_GetExportSaveAsFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, sZipFileName);

        //Start the activity:
        startActivityForResult(intent_GetExportSaveAsFile, REQUEST_CODE_GET_EXPORT_SAVEAS_FILE);

    }
```

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                 Intent resultData) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, resultData);

        Uri uriZipFile = resultData.getData();
        String sUriString = uriZipFile.toString();
        
        
        //Begin check for available space...
        
        //?????
        
        //...end check for available space.
        
        
        Intent ExportIntent = new Intent(this, ExportComicsService.class);
        ExportIntent.putExtra(ExportComicsService.ZIP_FILE, sUriString);

        startService(ExportIntent);
    }
```

Here is my code in my service, which creates the file output stream, but I would like to check for space before I get to this stage:

```
@Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        try {

            //create ZipOutputStream to write to the zip file
            String sUriString = intent.getStringExtra(ZIP_FILE);
            Uri uriZipFile = Uri.parse(sUriString);
            ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = getContentResolver().
                    openFileDescriptor(uriZipFile, "w");

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pfd.getFileDescriptor());
            ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);

            //Begin zip file processing....
            
            //...end zip file processing.

            zos.close();
            fos.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `I ask them to select a folder on their Android device to hold the zip file - it will most likely be an external SD card. I use Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT in order to create a new file, ` That is a strange scenario. If the user selected a folder you can create any file in that folder. You do not need that action then. Do the one or the other. Not both.

Comment: "I am unable to capture the device path so that I can check to make sure that there is enough storage space to hold the zip file" -- there is no concept of "enough storage space" for your app to really worry about. Bear in mind that there is no requirement that the user choose a `DocumentsProvider` that stores anything locally. For example, they might choose Google Drive.

Comment: @blackapps
Thank you for the reply. I think I can get away with asking them to select a folder, and then tell them the name of the zip file and give it a timestamp in the name.
The ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT intent is equivalent to SaveAs, if I am not mistaken, and the user can select both a location and a file name. The intent does not return the location, just a Uri to the potential file. Thus, I cannot be sure of the available space.

Comment: @CommonsWare
I hadn't even thought that the user might want to store to Google Drive. However, my intent was that it would be local for data privacy.

Comment: My point is that "available space" is a local storage concept, and the Storage Access Framework is not tied to local storage. If you are going to force the user to local storage, you will need to work with something like `getExternalFilesDir()` that you can access on Android 11 on down. If you are going to stick with the Storage Access Framework, then you will need to assume/hope that the user is handling storage space themselves.